# What is the best way to install openstack

Tags: juju, openstack, cloud, openstack-autopilot

I am trying to set up an openstack environment, but I am a bit confused due to the different mechanisms to do this. 
I have an environment with 8 nodes, and MAAS is installed at one node.( Ubuntu 15.04 with MAAS installation. The other 7 nodes are 14.04 LTS)

Now what ?

1. Use this procedure http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack and go for Landscape Autopilot to setup openstack ? There are also other choices in the install procedure
2. Install JUJU and use JUJU GUI to install Openstack ?
3. Install openstack step by step from shell ?
4. Openstack-autopilot (? is this the same as landscape-autopilot?)

Other ways ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the steps provided on this site: [OpenStack Install guide](http://docs.openstack.org/juno/install-guide/install/apt/content/)

Comment: Why to you think I should go for Juno instead of Kilo ?